# Texture from Blender doesn't appear in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I've searched endlessly for an answer to this question. However, I have created a model in Blender and export it as a .FBX directly into Unity. But the textures I have applied in Blender do not render in Unity (Even in the preview screen). I have UV Unwrapped the model, and created a custom texture pattern to suit. I've inserted the textures into Unity, however this just loads them how Unity feels, not how I'd like it to look.
I've attempted to add it as a .blend file, but Blender crashes, and it fails to convert to an .fbx file in Unity. The model is of a wall, with 3 doorways, and 3 doors. The wall has its own texture, and the doors all have the same texture. (I'd upload images but haven't earnt enough rep).
Is there a simple solution? Or am I over looking the whole process and missing something important out?

Comment: Have you tried importing your FBX back to blender? Is materials working correct in that case? If not, then your problem should be in the blender.

Comment: I havent created any materials or textures assigned to materials. Just simply UV unwrapped and edited in photoshop

Comment: I thought that you need to have a material to get rendering right in both Blender and Unity. It might be that without material Unity is applying texture to model without your unwrap. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure..Hence the question on here, I'll give it a try through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you UV unwrapped your model you save the uv in a file in blender you should apply that file as a texture to your model in unity and you will be done,tell me if you have already done that. [Here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2009/11/21/exporting-a-lowpoly-model-to-unity-3d/) are useful tutorials.

Comment: Could you give instructions? Thanks.

Comment: here are useful tutorials on this [link](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2009/11/21/exporting-a-lowpoly-model-to-unity-3d/)

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7Bncm2KGMo) is a tutorial on exporting model with texture and animation to unity

Comment: tell me if something happened

Comment: I'll have a play around with it. Do I need to create a material and assign the texture to it?

Comment: thats probably where I went wrong. I haven't created any materials I've just unwrapped and edited the mapping in photoshop. I'll follow the tutorials and let you know how I get on

Comment: just followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obB9T3jXlak) tutoral and learnt how to map textures with materials

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck exporting it as a wavefront object. Under transform select Path Mode: Copy and you should get your materials.