# Importing blender textured objects into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I am able to get this particular textured model from a 360 camera in blender. [Blender Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeEDr.jpg)

However, how do i get this .obj model into unity? I am only able to get the shaded version of it, not the textured version. [Unity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6wWp.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texture from Blender doesn't appear in Unity 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980055/texture-from-blender-doesnt-appear-in-unity-3d)

Answer (score 0):

When you export the .obj you should have a .mtl which contains the material data and texture mapping. Make sure when importing into unity (and exporting from blender) the file is generated and read.

Check your blender material properties and the individual texture properties. you should try to combine all materials into a single material so that its easier to reconfigure the textures in unity.

Once imported into unity, check the material settings and check if you need to reference the texture files again, most often when importing exporting .obj, the texture path gets lost so you must re-reference it in the target software. Sometimes it is also necessary to re-assign the materials themselves.

Also check your rendering options in unity, you may just be seeing it untextured in the unity viewport. (on the top left corner it says shaded, try changing it to textured or some other option)

You may as well try to use other mutually supported file types, like .3DS which do not use a separate material file, or check for blender add-ons that can export with all necessary settings for Unity.

Finally, your model is way too complex, it is raw data from a 3D scanner or ripper, I suggest you remake it so that you have manual control over each face and texture. (or at least for practice of doing the export-import operation).

More details like pictures of your material settings of both blender and unity would help in assisting you further.